# Android OS Updates On Nexus

Tags: updates, 6.0-marshmallow, 7.0-nougat

I was considering buying Nexus 6P however there would be new Nexus by next September so i was wondering if any one would clarify this rumor. A friend said that he heard from a Nexus user that a Nexus gets every Android OS Update so basically if the Nexus 6P which has Android Marshmallow right now would be immediately be  updated to Android Nougat when the update arrives and so on and so forth. Is this true or is my friend just messing with me.

Comment: This link will help you (look for Nexus devices)---  https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4457705?hl=en&ref_topic=3415518

Comment: @MANI You should post the relevant portion of that link as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Nexus devices generally get system updates in a timely manner, but only for a certain amount of time (as is generally the case for all devices). The Nexus 6P is guaranteed to be updated until [September 2017](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4457705#nexus_devices), so it will definitely receive the Android Nougat update.